# Hibernate Entity column name starting with underscore (_) ex: "_created" and "_updated" as column names

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I'm trying to represent entity with column names starting with _ and seeing issues with JPA recognizing the data in DB.

```
public class CommonBaseEntity {

    @CreationTimestamp
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "\"_created\"")
    private ZonedDateTime created;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "_updated")
    private ZonedDateTime updated;

}
```

i'm seeing the below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1506)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1538)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
        ... 73 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Maybe try delimiting the updated column name also: `@Column(name = "\"_updated\"")`. What is your target database? As different databases have different delimiters.

Comment: Thanks, That didn’t work. My target db is Oracle

Comment: Oracle uses double quotes (") for identifier delimiters; so that seems OK. But Oracle requires unquoted identifiers to begin with an alphabetic character; so that might be causing problems (although *quoted* identifiers can begin with any character...). You might investigate using the JPA `<delimited-identifiers/>` setting in your orm.xml.

Comment: Setting `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` to `true` in `persistence.xml` might also do the trick (without the need for any extra delimiters)

Comment: I'm using dropwizard and not spring framework. so cannot add that